# WGet multiple directoriesdirectories

Tags: wget

I am relatively new to the scene and am not that experienced with WGet (currently using VisualWGet, but also have cmd based WGet). I'm trying to download many (182,218 to be precise) images. I can get as far as downloading the first directory and all of the images within, then it will download only one image of each directory afterwards.

I am making sure to use a recursive search, but it seems like it does not want to enter the other directories after it exits out of the first one.

here's the process:

- Downloads everything in directory 0
- back tracks to parent directory
- downloads first image in directory 1
- downloads first image in directory 2
- etc

The directory i'm trying to download from is http://66.11.126.173/images/ and each directory doesn't seem to be a link, rather an image that doesn't link to another directory.

The images are listed in directories as such

- http://66.11.126.173/images/0/
- http://66.11.126.173/images/1/
- http://66.11.126.173/images/2/
- etc

each directory has 31 variations of the same image and there are 5878 directories and I start my downloads in images/0/ otherwise it will want to download the index.html file for /images/

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Operating system? On Linux you could easily say `for i in $(seq 0 5877); do for j in $(seq 0 31); do wget http://66.11.126.1/images/$i/$i_$j.png; done; done`. On Windows, `cmd` syntax is a little more verbose but `for /l` has the capability to generate a sequence of numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the OS. I'm operating on windows 7

Comment: On Windows, `for /l %i in (0, 1, 5877) do for /l %j in (0, 1, 31) do wget http://66.11.126.1/images/%i/%i_%j.png` should do it. (In a batch file you must of course double the `%` signs.)

Comment: Awesome, It worked! Thank you. They all downloaded into a single folder, but that's not an issue. I can use AHK to easily arrange them from here. Just couldn't quite figure out how to download them all :)   Much appreciated

Comment: What about downloading a **specific file type** using **VisualWget**? Is it possible to download only **mp3** files in a directory and its sub-directories in **VisualWget**?